# Raspberry webserver change website name

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver

In my browser i can type 192.168.178.33:8000  to access the webpages on my raspberry or

> http://raspberrypi:8000/

Somewhere must be set that the web browser translate http://raspberrypi:8000/ into 192.168.178.33:8000  I tried to find a nameserver but I've no idea what or where I can change this

Is there a simple way to change
http://raspberrypi:8000/    into http://whateverIWantHere:8000/

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your hosts file. The location is different for each OS and may also be different for different versions of the OS. Note that you only need to do the changes on the computer where you want to translate it.

Windows 10:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Linux/Raspbian:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
192.168.178.33 raspberrypi
```

You may have to restart, I'm not sure if the changes will apply immediately. And you can now type 192.168.178.33:8080 in your browser.